# HighChart not displaying 'table' in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am using HighChart in reactjs project. It displays chart properly, but it doesn't show table. I am using `showTable:true` in `config`.

I have created project in codesandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/wy2v4p0r5k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import Highcharts `exporting` and `export-data` modules:

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts";

require("highcharts/modules/exporting.js")(Highcharts);
require("highcharts/modules/export-data.js")(Highcharts);
```

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/yw11p8wpw9

Also, I recommend you to use the `highcharts-react-official` wrapper, which is officially supported: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official

Comment: Is there any option to hide chart and display only table?

Comment: Hi @Shashidhara, Yes, please check the second example in the API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.showTable

Comment: Is it possible to use same concept in ReactJs?

Comment: @Shashidhara, Yes, of course. Please check this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nmo4ow7kj

Comment: One issue am facing, Actually i am using toggle between table and chart. It display table but not showing chart on toggle button click. https://codesandbox.io/s/p5mwy02w1j

Comment: @Shashidhara, Let's continue the thread in this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55069255/reactjs-highcharts-toggle-table-and-chart-not-updating/55097622#55097622